# How to fork multiple processes from a same parent？

Tags: linux, c++, fork, process

I am trying to create multiple processes from a same parent, but it always ended up with more processes than expected. I couldn't figure out how to do it and need some help here.

I found a piece of code online and tried it,

```
int main ()
{
    pid_t pid=0;
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        pid=fork();
        switch(pid)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                cout<<"\nI am a child and my pid is:"<<getpid();
                cout<<endl;
                exit(0);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                cout<<"\nI am a parent and my pid is: "<<getpid();
                cout<<"\nMy child pid is: "<<pid;
                cout<<endl;
                wait(NULL);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
  return 0;
 }
```

This code does work and creates 3 children from same parent. However, it seems like that's because after each child process was created, it was terminated immediately. So it won't fork more grandchild process in the next round of for loop. But I need to keep these child processes running for sometime and they need to communicate with the parents.

Comment: Is it producing the output "I am a child ... "? Once you call exit the process ends. The reason they end so fast is that you aren't doing anything in the process. You should call some CPU-intensive function instead of printing and immediately exiting.

Comment: This is not a problem with fork but a simple logic problem. `fork()` returns 0 in the child. Trace on paper what is happening here, without the `exit` for the child, the loop run again, and `fork` is executed again. What you want to do is *if* the process is the child, you go out of the loop, *else* you continue looping and forking ...

Comment: Thank you both for answering my question. I modified my code by using if..else instead of case..switch, and adding a break at the end of the forked child process to get out of the loop, and it works!!!!! I got exactly what I want!

Comment: Do not call `exit` in the children. This causes `atexit` tasks (such as flushing buffers) to occur more than once. Use `_exit`.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're actually asking. Your code achieves the objective in your title. At the end of the body, you state what you really want to do. But you don't ask any question about how to do it. So you'll get silly answer like "code what you need and if you run into trouble, ask for help".

Comment: An example https://stackoverflow.com/a/55972296/412080

Comment: Pro tip: Don't start your printout with an end-of-line character. Put it at the end of the line, as the name suggests! Standard output is line buffered, so nothing is actually printed until an end-of-line character is added, or the process terminates. That makes it very hard to know what happens in your program, since after a fork() call the child process inherits the output buffer, with the unfinished and unprinted line in it, and the actual printing is then done later, perhaps twice - once in the parent and once in the child! (And yes, the extra printing of an endl fixes this.)

Comment: So don't have the child immediately exit! Instead of `exit(0)`, just do `int rv = do_something(); exit(rv);`

Answer (score 0):

A child process may immediately break the loop to continue its work outside

```
int main ()
{
   cout<<"\nI am a parent and my pid is: "<<getpid()<<endl;

   pid_t pid;
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
       pid=fork();
       if(pid == -1)
       {
           cout<<"Error in fork()"<<endl;
           return 1;
       }
       if(pid == 0)
           break;
       cout<<"My child "<<i<<" pid is: "<<pid<<endl;
    }

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        cout<<"I am a child  "<<i<<" and my pid is "<<getpid()<<endl;
        wait(NULL);  // EDIT: this line is wrong!
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"I am a parent :)"<<endl;
        wait(NULL);  // EDIT: this line is wrong!
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
The `wait(NULL)` lines are wrong. If the process has no children active, `wait()` has no effect, so it's useless in children here. OTOH in the parent process `wait()` suspends the execution until *any* of children exits. We have three children here, so would have to `wait()` three times. Additionally one can't know in advance the order of children completion, so we would need much more sophisticated code for that. Something like this:

```
struct WORK_DESCRIPTION {
    int    childpid;
    // any other data - what a child has to do
} work[3];

for(i=1; i<3; i++) {
    pid=fork();
    ...
    work[i].childpid = pid;
}

if(pid == 0)    // in a child
{
    do_something( work[i] );
}
else
{
    int childpid;
    while(childpid = wait(NULL), childpid != 0)
    {
        // a child terminated - find out which one it was

        for(i=0; i<3; i++)
            if(work[i].childpid == childpid)
            {
                // use the i-th child results here
            }
    }
    // wait returned 0 - no more children to wait for
}
```

Comment: I am still a bit confused about the pid here. In the above code, you fork all 3 children first in the for loop, then you use if(pid==0) to let each child print a msg. That's fine, because they all do the same thing. But what if I want each child to do a different job, how could I select a child in this case?  What I did is I fork a child, if pid == 0, do something; else (back to parent), fork 2nd child, if pid ==0, do another thing, and so on. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Every child proces inherits a copy of its parent data, and the `i` variable among them (that's why I print it here). So you can make a `switch(i){...}` to select appropriate work for each child. Caution: there's no 'back to parent', I mean the child proces does no 'return'. Since `fork()` the parent and the child run simulaneously. You need to `wait()` in the parent process if you want to synchronize it with children (e.g. use their results).

Comment: The way I described in en edit you use results of children processes ass soon as they are available. You can also make it simpler with 3-parameter `wait()`, just waiting for children in the order they were started instead of catching as they complete: `for(i=0;i<3;i++) {wait(work[i].childpid, ..., ...); ...}` (or possibly there is a corresponding 1-parameter `waitpid()` function - see the man pages).